# Class does not exist [] [] in magento 2.4.3

Tags: magento2

I am trying to create a new module in my account page but i am unable to get block information magento2

here is my file

/app/code/Custom/Loa/Block/Account/temp.php

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Loa\Block\Account;


use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;


class Temp extends Template
{


    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $registry;



    protected $customerSession;

    protected $url;

    /**
     * Cancel constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     */
    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        array $data = [],

        Session $customerSession,

    ) {


        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve current order model instance
     *
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Model\Order
     */
    public function getCustomer()
    {
        return $this->customerSession->getCustomer();
    }





}/
```

/end class

I am trying to access the block in phtml file as

```
$blockObj= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Custom/Loa/Block/Account/Temp');
```

Here is my xml file
/app/code/Custom/Loa/view/frontend/layout/loa_account_temp.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
           
            <block class="Custom/Loa/Block/Account/Temp" name="custom_loa_content" template="Custom_Loa::loas.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

But getting error as  main.CRITICAL: Error: Class 'Custom/Loa/Block/Account/Temp' not found in /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121
Stack trace:

what am i missing in this ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your layout file, it should be below format otherwise it will not redirect in your template.

**Layout file format.**

{router_id}*{controller_name}*{action_name}.xml.

Comment: I have added my xml file

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us what are you trying to achieve?

/app/code/Custom/Loa/Block/Account/temp.php - capitalize the file name if not capitalized. Also, delete the trailing comma from the last argument inside the constructor `Session $customerSession,` should be `Session $customerSession`>

Inside the phtml file you can access block methods like this: `$customer = $block->getCustomer()` because you have declared `<block class="Custom/Loa/Block/Account/Temp"` inside your layout.

Try to use ViewModel instead of Block https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/view-models.html

Do you have a controller setup for /loa/account/temp? https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/create-a-new-page/